# Reshape and filter pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to filter out all the values from the dataframe below (df1) with cells equal to 1 and create a new dataframe where each row has the row and column from the corresponding cell (as in df2 below):

```
dict1 = [{'12/21/18': 0,'12/22/18': 0,'12/23/18': 1,'12/24/18': 1},
     {'12/21/18': 1,'12/22/18': 1,'12/23/18': 0,'12/24/18': 1},
     {'12/21/18': 0,'12/22/18': 1,'12/23/18': 0,'12/24/18': 0},
     {'12/21/18': 1,'12/22/18': 0,'12/23/18': 1,'12/24/18': 1}]


df1 = pd.DataFrame(dict1, index= ['AAPL','CSCO','GE','MSFT' ])

dict2 = [{'Ticker': 'AAPL','Date': '12/23/18'},
     {'Ticker': 'AAPL','Date': '12/24/18'},
     {'Ticker': 'CSCO','Date': '12/22/18'},
     {'Ticker': 'CSCO','Date': '12/24/18'},
     {'Ticker': 'GE',  'Date': '12/22/18'},
     {'Ticker': 'MSFT','Date': '12/24/18'}]


df2 = pd.DataFrame(dict2)
```

Can anyone suggest an approach of how to do so?

Comment: You just need melt and filter it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the performance comparison of methods given by @slayer and @Lucas H. I've also added a third approach.

```
@slayer method 
%%timeit 
1.12 ms ± 61.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

@Lucas H method
%%timeit
5.16 ms ± 735 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

@Third method
%%timeit
4.4 ms ± 232 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)


# Third method
df1 = df1.T
df2 = pd.melt(df1.where(df1==0, df1.index))
df2 = df2[df2.value != 0]
df2.columns = ['Ticker', 'Date']
```

Clearly @slayer's method beats all.

Comment: Thank you for the comparison and thanks also for the third approach, really appreciate the help. I might still go with Lucas' or your method because speed is no concern and because I really want to familiarize myself with melt!!

Comment: Nice comparison. Sometimes the efficient route is not the one most sought after.

Comment: Really good to know, in case I have to apply this to larger datasets, I will keep your approach in my cheatsheet slayer just in case, thank to all 3 of you!!! This has been very helpful!!!

Comment: Thanks meW, this is going to be very helpful!!

Answer (score 1):

You can try looking at the values of the dataframe and get an array of indices where the value is greater than 0. Then you can use the indices into the index and column name lists to build a new dataframe.

```
import numpy as np
idx = np.argwhere(df1.values > 0)

# Get a list of the ticker index and column names
ticker_list = df1.index.tolist()
date_list = df1.columns.tolist()
ticker = []
date = []

for value in idx:
    ticker.append(ticker_list[value[0]])
    date.append(date_list[value[1]])

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Ticker': ticker, 'Date': date})
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that the simplest way to do this is as follows:

```
df1.index.name = 'Ticker' # First reset the name so it will match your desired output (default is 'index')
df2 = df1.reset_index().melt(id_vars='Ticker',var_name='Date') # This unstacks the data
```

Finally to get it into your desired form, we remove 0's, reset the index, and sort:

```
df2 = df2[df2.value == 1].set_index('Ticker').filter(['Date','Ticker']).sort_index()
```