# Reshape dataframe while avoiding memory error

Tags: python, dataframe, reshape

I would like to reshape a large dataframe from the format in df1 to df2::

I have asked this question before in this post:

[Reshape and filter pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53951753/reshape-and-filter-pandas-dataframe)

and received 3 suggested approaches which all work for the min example below however all lead to a memory error when used on the actual dataframe.

```
dict1 = [{'12/21/18': 0,'12/22/18': 0,'12/23/18': 1,'12/24/18': 1},
 {'12/21/18': 1,'12/22/18': 1,'12/23/18': 0,'12/24/18': 1},
 {'12/21/18': 0,'12/22/18': 1,'12/23/18': 0,'12/24/18': 0},
 {'12/21/18': 1,'12/22/18': 0,'12/23/18': 1,'12/24/18': 1}]


df1 = pd.DataFrame(dict1, index= ['AAPL','CSCO','GE','MSFT' ])

dict2 = [{'Ticker': 'AAPL','Date': '12/23/18'},
 {'Ticker': 'AAPL','Date': '12/24/18'},
 {'Ticker': 'CSCO','Date': '12/22/18'},
 {'Ticker': 'CSCO','Date': '12/24/18'},
 {'Ticker': 'GE',  'Date': '12/22/18'},
 {'Ticker': 'MSFT','Date': '12/24/18'}]


df2 = pd.DataFrame(dict2)
```

For example, this does work for the small example:

```
df1.index.name = 'Ticker' 
df2 = df1.reset_index().melt(id_vars='Ticker',var_name='Date') 

df2 = df2[df2.value == 1].set_index('Ticker').filter(['Date','Ticker']).sort_index()
```

Can anyone suggest how I can avoid the memory error? Would there be a way to run the whole thing in litte smaller chunks and save them in between to avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you tried [stack](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html).

```
import pandas as pd

dict1 = [{'12/21/18': 0,'12/22/18': 0,'12/23/18': 1,'12/24/18': 1},
 {'12/21/18': 1,'12/22/18': 1,'12/23/18': 0,'12/24/18': 1},
 {'12/21/18': 0,'12/22/18': 1,'12/23/18': 0,'12/24/18': 0},
 {'12/21/18': 1,'12/22/18': 0,'12/23/18': 1,'12/24/18': 1}]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(dict1, index= ['AAPL','CSCO','GE','MSFT'])
df1.index.name = 'Ticker'

df3 = df1.stack()
df3 = df3[df3 == 1].reset_index(level=1)
df3.rename(columns={'level_1': 'Date'})[['Date']]
```

[image: Output]

Comment: It only works for the small example, for the larger one I also get a memory error.